# Difficulty in setting up jekyll theme for github page

Tags: github, github-pages

I have enabled github  [page](https://deepakgarg0802.github.io/XYZReader/)  for my  [repository](https://github.com/deepakgarg0802/XYZReader). I am trying to set up theme for the page using repository settings. When I selected the theme ,a `_config.yml` file was generated in docs folder. But no theme is there on github page. Do I need to add any other file in `/docs/` folder apart from `index.html` and `_config.yml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Github support team, I got the solution. I added this front matter at the top of my HTML file, that made the theme styles applied:

```
---
layout: default
---
```

If you use Markdown, the theme would be applied automatically so converting your HTML to Markdown is another option.